# can we Execute any sql query in sql loader control file

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-loader

Can we execute any SQL statement using sql control file.
the pseudocode is like

```
 LOAD DATA        
    INFILE *          
    DELETE *from STUDENT WHERE STATUS="PASS_OUT"**

    APPEND                          
    INTO TABLE STUDENT WHEN (1:1)= '1'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 

    .......................

    ..........................
```

**ERROR**

```
 SQL*Loader-350: Syntax error at line X. 
    Expecting ".......", found keyword delete.
    DELETE * from STUDENT where STATUS='PASS_OUT' 
    ^
```

> NOTE:-where "......." is different keywords based on their places.

Comment: Try it simply. Are you getting error if yes then share same, people will help to resolve. If no then you can do it.

Comment: @Panther The Error is 


SQL*Loader-350: Syntax error at line X.
Expecting ".......", found keyword delete.
DELETE * from STUDENT where STATUS='PASS_OUT' 
^
NOTE:-where "......." is different keywords based on place.

Comment: Why this down casting.Every one is not an expert in every technologies. and also I did enough R&D before posting it on the forum.which is clear enough from the pesudocode. Anyway no problem.

Comment: Please add same in question. As it will help people to help you.

Comment: Don't worry about the downcasting of  question, just try to improve. People downvote for knowledge of technology but for how much effort you putted before asking or may be grammer of question. Initally, it seemed as if you just posted question being lazy to check by your self

Comment: It's pretty clear [from the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_control_file.htm#SUTIL005), that you can't have SQL statements in the control file.

Answer (score 0):

No, you would have to create a wrapper script around your SQL*Loader call  that does that first and on success runs sqlldr.

Comment: can you please give any good link to create wrapper script in easy steps.

Comment: That depends on your environment. For example, if you were running on UNIX you could write a shell script that would first run the delete, via sqlplus or something, then run SQL*Loader.  Do a little searching, there are a lot of examples.  I'm sure you can find some for your environment.